# EJS file opens as a static HTML instead of JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Im making a simple Express todo app using EJS as my view engine.

It looks exactly like this on the page when I open in default browser (Chrome)...

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Express To-Do</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Todos as of <%= time %></h1>
    <ul>
      <% todos.forEach(function(t, idx) { %>
        <li>
          <a href="/todos/<%= idx %>"><%= t.todo %></a>
            - 
          <%= t.done ? 'done' : 'not done' %>
        </li>
      <% }); %>
    </ul>
    <a href="/todos/new">Add To-do</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I opened a new project and its HTML file rendered normally but when I reopened former projects that used to render fine they also appear like the code above with hardcoded structure. I also tried reinstalling using npm install ejs and restarting VSCode but no luck. I also doubled checked my extension was still installed to open in browser (because I have to manually select 'open in other browser'... 'chrome' because my open in default browser isn't working as of today).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm not sure why none of them are working anymore.

Comment: EJS is intended to look like HTML when you inspect it in the browser. You shouldn't see any of the EJS markup like `<%`. Unless you're not seeing the markup within VS code, is what you mean?

Comment: Can you post your `root` file from where did you render

Comment: @RGreenstreet When I open it in the browser all of the markup is still showing. The code above is exactly how it opens so those <% are all rendering in my Chrome view

Comment: Could you add the `view-engine` declaration that's in place in your app.js? Also just to confirm, this file is saved as `.ejs`, correct?